# How to perform left joins on multiple tables along with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, case, distinct

```
SELECT 
posts.id,posts.user_id,
username, title,posts.body as post_body, posts.created_at, posts.is_open, posts.views as views, users.photoUrl,
COUNT(DISTINCT answers.id) as answer_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) as comment_count,
COUNT (CASE answers.approved WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as correct_count,
GROUP_CONCAT(tagname) as tags
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posttag ON posts.id = post_id 
JOIN tags ON tag_id = tags.id 
JOIN users ON user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.post_id = posts.id 
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id 
WHERE posts.id = ?;
```

I am trying to query every post with its corresponding answers, comments and tags.

However in my query result, I get 8 tags when there are 4

The COUNT correct_count changes from from 1 to 4

How can I get the correct data?

Comment: Peform the aggregations in separate subqueries.  You might also want to add sample data to your question.

Comment: Inner joinings kills above left joining converting them to inner ones (`posttag`).

Comment: @Akina I followed forpas' answer without changing the order of the joins. It gave me the desired result. Thanks anyway, I knew the joins affected each other but couldn't find on the internet how that happened.

Comment: This is not an error. This simply instructs the server to perform the operation whose result wil be unconditionally rejected in future... but if you want to provide additional work to your server then everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` for `correct_count` and `tags` also:

```
.....................................
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN answers.approved THEN answers.id END) as correct_count,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tagname) as tags
```